# Tedit.onkeyup + message() or inputbox confirmed with return key infinitely calls Tedit.onkeyup again

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Bit embarrassed, but I cant figure out a proper way to solve this problem. 
I have a single Tedit class component on my form where user inputs some commands or parameters. when something is wrong or needs additional input, a message box or input box is shown. 
when an user is confirming message box with an return key - vk_return, tedit onkeyup is called again, infinitely unless user is confirming message with a mouse.

To solve this, I usually temporarily changed focus to another component before showing the message.

Can someone please explain me why is that happening
How can I avoid that behaviour?

```
procedure Tform1.Edit_INPUTKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if ord(Key) = VK_RETURN then // ENTER
  begin    
    if Edit_INPUT.text = '' then
    begin
      showmessage('edit box is empty!');
    end;    
  end;
end;
```

edited....

based on @sddk pointing out the cause of my problem, came up with this:

```
private
Edit1_lastkeyevent_keyup: boolean;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
Edit1_lastkeyevent_keyup := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
if ord(Key) = vk_return then
   begin
   if Edit1_lastkeyevent_keyup = false then
      begin
      if Edit1.Text = '' then
         begin
         showmessage('edit box is empty!');
         end;
      end;
   end;
Edit1_lastkeyevent_keyup := true;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use KeyDown event of edit instead of KeyUp.

When the user confirm messagebox with return key, the Keydown event closes the messagebox and keyUp event is handled by edit.

...update...

To prevent that the code run repeatedly 100 times while return key is pressed down below codes may be used.

```
private // class private
  valueChanged:Boolean;

procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  valueChanged := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Ord(Key) = VK_RETURN then
    if Edit1.Text = '' then
      begin
        if valueChanged then
          begin
            valueChanged := False;
            ShowMessage('edit box is empty!');
          end;
      end
    else
      begin
        // code your job here
      end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  valueChanged := True;
end;
```

Comment: why did I miss this obvious behaviour lol. Ok, then how would you suggest to handle Keydown events so that logical code does not run repeatedly 100 times while return key is pressed down?

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy have a look at my update. i could not found a way by dont using a private variable.

Comment: After you pointed out the reason of onkeyup and messagebox events that caused that misbehaviour, I thought something similar. Still kept all logics in unkeyup event

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy will you share your solution with us?

Comment: If no one comes up with more complete or better way to solve this problem, i'll accept your answer. many thanks to pointing out the obvious  I couldn't see :)

Comment: Is there a reason you need this to work on KeyUp or KeyDown and couldn't have used KeyPress?